# Sharing to social media, specifically Facebook

Tags: android, facebook-java-api

I've got a weird issue. I need to share different content depending on the social media that has been selected.

I found something that allows me to do it, it just becomes a problem when i need to implement sharing to facebook (Facebook ignores the intent)

This is the method i am using (Not in the fragment its self hence passing the Fragment)

It worked fine (Sending to twitter "abc" and sending to sms "def" for example).

The minute i implemented facebook its crashing with the below stacktrace

```
public static void onShareClick(Fragment context, Trade trade) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent();
    emailIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    // Native email client doesn't currently support HTML, but it doesn't hurt to try in case they fix it
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(resources.getString(R.string.share_email_native).replace(resources.getString(R.string.share_trade_url_placeholder), StringUtils.decodeUrl(StringUtils.createItemURIWithTitle(trade.getTradeId(), trade.getTitle())))));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, resources.getString(R.string.share_email_subject));
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

    PackageManager pm = context.getActivity().getPackageManager();
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");


    Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, resources.getString(R.string.share_chooser_text));

    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
    List<LabeledIntent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) {
      // Extract the label, append it, and repackage it in a LabeledIntent
      ResolveInfo ri = resInfo.get(i);
      String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
      if (packageName.contains("android.email")) {
        emailIntent.setPackage(packageName);
      } else if (packageName.contains("twitter") || packageName.contains("facebook") || packageName.contains("mms") || packageName.contains("android.gm")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, ri.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        if (packageName.contains("twitter")) {
          //aContext.getString(R.string.social_tweet_look_at_this_on_myapp_text) + StringUtils.decodeUrl(StringUtils.createItemURIWithTitle(aTradeId, tradeTitle)) + aContext.getString(R.string.social_tweet_hashtag_myapp_text)
          intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, resources.getString(R.string.share_twitter).replace(resources.getString(R.string.share_trade_url_placeholder), StringUtils.decodeUrl(StringUtils.createItemURIWithTitle(trade.getTradeId(), trade.getTitle()))));
        } else if (packageName.contains("facebook")) {
          if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
            ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentTitle("This is the title")
                    .setContentDescription("This is the description")
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("www.google.com"))
                    .build();
            ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(context);
//---------This is where the error is----------//
            shareDialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);
          }

//          intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, resources.getString(R.string.share_facebook).replace(resources.getString(R.string.share_trade_url_placeholder), StringUtils.decodeUrl(StringUtils.createItemURIWithTitle(trade.getTradeId(), trade.getTitle()))));

          // Warning: Facebook IGNORES our text. They say "These fields are intended for users to express themselves. Pre-filling these fields erodes the authenticity of the user voice."
          // One workaround is to use the Facebook SDK to post, but that doesn't allow the user to choose how they want to share. We can also make a custom landing page, and the link
          // will show the <meta content ="..."> text from that page with our link in Facebook.
        } else if (packageName.contains("mms")) {
          intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, resources.getString(R.string.share_sms).replace(resources.getString(R.string.share_trade_url_placeholder), StringUtils.decodeUrl(StringUtils.createItemURIWithTitle(trade.getTradeId(), trade.getTitle()))));
        } else if (packageName.contains("android.gm")) { // If Gmail shows up twice, try removing this else-if clause and the reference to "android.gm" above
          intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(resources.getString(R.string.share_email_gmail).replace(resources.getString(R.string.share_trade_url_placeholder), StringUtils.decodeUrl(StringUtils.createItemURIWithTitle(trade.getTradeId(), trade.getTitle())))));
          intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, resources.getString(R.string.share_email_subject));
          intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        }

        intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, packageName, ri.loadLabel(pm), ri.icon));
      }
    }

    // convert intentList to array
    LabeledIntent[] extraIntents = intentList.toArray(new LabeledIntent[intentList.size()]);

    openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
    context.startActivity(openInChooser);
  }
```

> ```
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                       Process: com.myApp.app, PID: 532
>                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
>                           at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:746)
>                           at com.facebook.internal.Utility.getDialogFeatureConfig(Utility.java:922)
>                           at com.facebook.internal.DialogPresenter.getVersionSpecForFeature(DialogPresenter.java:254)
>                           at com.facebook.internal.DialogPresenter.getProtocolVersionForNativeDialog(DialogPresenter.java:241)
>                           at com.facebook.internal.DialogPresenter.canPresentNativeDialogWithFeature(DialogPresenter.java:75)
>                           at com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog.canShowNative(ShareDialog.java:162)
>                           at com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog.access$300(ShareDialog.java:65)
>                           at com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog$NativeHandler.canShow(ShareDialog.java:314)
>                           at com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog$NativeHandler.canShow(ShareDialog.java:285)
>                           at com.facebook.internal.FacebookDialogBase.createAppCallForMode(FacebookDialogBase.java:210)
>                           at com.facebook.internal.FacebookDialogBase.showImpl(FacebookDialogBase.java:150)
>                           at com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog.show(ShareDialog.java:267)
>                           at com.myApp.app.item.overview.OverviewListItemFragment.onShareClick(OverviewListItemFragment.java:908)
>                           at com.myApp.app.item.overview.OverviewListItemFragment.onClick(OverviewListItemFragment.java:841)
>                           at com.myApp.app.item.overview.OverviewListItemFragment_ViewBinding$10.doClick(OverviewListItemFragment_ViewBinding.java:169)
>                           at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
>                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4802)
>                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20101)
>                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
>                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
>                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
>                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
>                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
> ```